# How to fetch last value from path string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Here , is my string

"C:\Users\Nishanth\AppData\Local\Temp\matel\192.168.0.156 (Remote)"

I want to fetch last value of this path i.e

> 192.168.0.156 (Remote)

Please  help me to fetch this value from a string

Comment: Is "192.168.0.156 (Remote)" supposed to be the name of the file, or a directory?

Comment: It will be directory name.

Comment: I dont mean to be a stick in the mud but surely this is a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be to use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Nishanth\AppData\Local\Temp\matel\192.168.0.156 (Remote)";
var folderName = Path.GetFileName(path).Dump();
```

Note: You may need to import the `System.IO` namespace:

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: OP stated in comments it's not supposed to be a file name. I think using this method doesn't clearly represent the intent.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I'm well aware, but this method still gives the correct answer, and without insantiating a `DirectoryInfo` object. Feel free to try it out :)

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't produce the correct result, I said it doesn't communicate intent clearly.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Well that's the fault of the people who wrote the API, not me...

Comment: No it isn't. `192.168.0.156 (Remote)` could easily be the name of a file.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli What are you talking about? OP said it's a directory and this code does *exactly* what is asked for.

Comment: Imagine you ran across this line while maintaining some code: `var folderName = Path.GetFileName(path);` Would you not be a little confused? Why is the variable called `folderName` if it's supposed to be getting a file name from the method it's calling. The answer from @Enigmativity communicates the intent of the code (to get the last part of the path) much more clearly.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli That's what comments are for. Both answers are correct, both work, Enig's answer has a better name for the method used, mine doesn't require an object to be instantiated. Code isn't always perfect to read.

Comment: I would value something more readable over any potential concerns about creating an object instance. Unless OP is doing it many times in short order it's unlikely to make any tangible difference in terms of performance.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Exactly, you don't know what OP is doing with this code, nor do you know what subsequent visitors to this post are doing. We're not here just to answer what OP is looking for, we are creating a repository of Q&A for all future visitors.

Comment: " I think using this method doesn't clearly represent the intent." Agree or disagree?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli You can keep labouring about that point all you like, I'm saying it's not relevant. This conversation is going nowhere because you are refusing to read what I write, so I'm giving up.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Nishanth\AppData\Local\Temp\matel\192.168.0.156 (Remote)";
var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var name = di.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var path=@"C:\Users\Nishanth\AppData\Local\Temp\matel\192.168.0.156 (Remote)";
string[] tokens = path.Split('\\');
var result=tokens[tokens.length-1]; // what you need
```